# Does D3 support multiple brushes on the same line chart?

Tags: d3.js

I want to create 2 brushes on the same line chart to pick 2 different date range for comparison.

brush1 :stDate,edDate
brush2: stDate1,edDate1

I see only one brush. How do I get the extents of another brush. Does D3 support multiple brushes on the same line chart? I want to see both the brush extents on the same line charts probably with different color schema

```
    var data=[{"Date":"20060215","ExamCount":1393},
    {"Date":"20060216","ExamCount":4159}, 
    {"Date":"20060217","ExamCount":0620},
    {"Date":"20060220","ExamCount":7191},
    {"Date":"20060221","ExamCount":798},
    {"Date":"20060223","ExamCount":5678},    
    {"Date":"20060224","ExamCount":3511},
    {"Date":"20060227","ExamCount":5978}, 
    {"Date":"20060228","ExamCount":3510},
    {"Date":"20060302","ExamCount":5711},
    {"Date":"20060303","ExamCount":5715},   
    {"Date":"20060304","ExamCount":6671},
    {"Date":"20060306","ExamCount":5714},
    {"Date":"20060307","ExamCount":9333},    
    {"Date":"20060308","ExamCount":2312}];
    var now = new Date(); 
    ts_start = '20060215';
    ts_end = '20060225';

    ts_start1 = '20060304';
    ts_end1 = '20060308';
    var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 100, left: 40},
    width = 1160 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 220 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    //width = 950, height = 90;
    var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
      y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

    ts_start=parseDate(ts_start);
    ts_end=parseDate(ts_end);
    ts_start1=parseDate(ts_start1);
    ts_end1=parseDate(ts_end1);

    //Data Population
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"),
        yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

    brush = d3.svg.brush()
          .x(x)
          //.on("brushend", brushended);
    brush1 = d3.svg.brush()
          .x(x)
          //.on("brushend", brushended);



 //$.getJSON(uri, function (data){
    var area = d3.svg.area()
      .interpolate("monotone")
      .x(function(d) { return x(d.Date); })
      .y0(height)
      .y1(function(d) { return y(d.ExamCount); });

    var svg = d3.select("#timeslider").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(10,0)");


    svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip")
      .append("rect")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.Date = parseDate(d.Date);
      d.ExamCount = + d.ExamCount;
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.Date; })));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return d.ExamCount; }))]);

    svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
      .attr("d", area);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x brush")
      .call(brush.extent([ts_start,ts_end]))
      .call(brush1.extent([ts_start1,ts_end1]))
      .selectAll("rect")
          .attr("height",height)
          .style({
              "fill": "#69f",
              "fill-opacity": "0.1"
          });
```

I only see the last brush but previous brush extent does not seem to appear. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: You can have as many brushes as you like. To be able to use them you would have to make sure that they don't overlap completely.

Comment: I have pasted my code. I see only one brush range and previous one is not visible? Am I missing anything or do I have to do in a different way?

Comment: My Code in jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bxW9T/1/

Comment: You do need to attach them to different elements -- http://jsfiddle.net/bxW9T/3/ They overlap completely though in this example so you can use only one of them.

Comment: Thanks I see the 2 brushes now. I am only able to change the brush range for second but when I change the the first one it always goes and overlaps with the second brush. I need to get 2 sets of dates and do a comparison. http://jsfiddle.net/bxW9T/5 –  Shanthi

Comment: You need non-overlapping elements to attach the brush behaviours to.

Comment: I am not sure what to you mean by non-overlapping elements. The time range of the extents are different though. Can you let me know how do I have non-overlapping elements?

Comment: Something like this -- http://jsfiddle.net/bxW9T/6/

Comment: Thanks, that helps.  I changed the brush positions/ranges of both the brushes but only one date value of the brush changes in the brushended(), while the other one is the same which I initially passed

Comment: You need different handler functions as well.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Do I need to do this in the brushended function? Do you have any sample or pointers?

Comment: This [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063663) isn't quite what you're looking for, but maybe it helps?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I will check this example and see.

Comment: Works!. Added some handler functions and it works!

Comment: Lars, I liked your approach to help me. Is there a way to give credit for your help?

Comment: I want to check this answer. How can i do this?

Comment: @ Shanthi If Lars doesn't come back and post a short summary answer recapping the comments within a day or so, you can post your own summary and mark it as accepted.  Glad you two got it figured out.  @LarsKotthoff: Post an answer, will you?  Even if you don't need the rep, it gets it out of the unanswered queue!

Comment: Sure, will do. Just didn't see it earlier because I need to sleep sometimes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D3 doesn't restrict the number of brushes you can have. There are two things to keep in mind:

- The elements you attach the brushes to should be separate and not overlap. If they overlap, one brush will receive events from the other; that is, you won't be able to actually use both brushes.
- The handler functions need to be different. That is, the events from one brush shouldn't affect the other.

Here is an [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063663) that uses several brushes that should give you an idea how to do it in your own code.